# How can I use a text file as database in Python?

Tags: python, database, python-2.7

I want to know what is the efficient way to insert several data to text file as database logic?

For instance I have set of cars, these cars have their `id, name`, and `color` variable.

```
id | name | color
1  | car1 | green
2  | car2 | red
3  | car3 | blue
```

I want to insert the data above to text file using python.

Later on I want to search a car, for instance based on its color.

Which method should I follow? An example with an explanation will really be appreciated!

Comment: why use a text file as a database?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint to gain experience.

Comment: Read `Pandas`, you can use `DataFrames`

Comment: You should definitely take a look at [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)..

Comment: If you want to use database logic based on a single file, have a look at [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3).

Comment: @dot.Py I did the same thing with sqlite very easily. I just want to learn the skills of pyhton with practising these kind of work. :) Thanks though

Comment: @ChristianKönig Like I said above, I just want to practise but I got stuck since I don't have much knowledge about pyhton, that is why ive just asked a way out :)

Comment: You question is rather broad for SO rules... Anyway here are some hints. As lines are not guaranteed to all have same length a text file cannot be used in a direct access mode, but only sequentially. That means that you should only add at the end of file, eventually  do in place replacement **for exactly the same number of chars**, and rewrite everything from the beginning for any other case. As a practicing exercise, you could load the text file in memory at the beginning of the prog and save it at the end.

Comment: You could use csv files.  Basically, you comma separate values (or you could separate using `|`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you Serge, I will read the rules carefully and try to avoid breaking them. Also thanks for the hint, I will try it now, I thought If I store each line (element) like `id, name, color` later on I can search based on `,` in each line.

Comment: Have you tried with [tinydb](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this simple case I would definitely recommend you to use [tinyDB](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb):

- it's really tiny
- written in pure Python
- works with Python 2.7 and 3.6 as well
- you can easily extend it
- fast installation with pip: `pip install tinydb`

It's definitely not for advance purposes (managing relationships or having ACID), but very flexible text file based storage, really easy to use. Check the link above.

For your case you can do something like this:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB
db = TinyDB('path_to_your_db_folder/db.json')
db.insert({'id': 1, 'name': 'car1', 'color': 'green'})
db.insert({'id': 2, 'name': 'car2', 'color': 'red'})
db.insert({'id': 3, 'name': 'car3', 'color': 'blue'})
```

You see, it's simple Python `dict`.

Querying is also simple:

- get all with `db.all()`
- query your data:

  ```
  from tinydb import Query
  Cars = Query()
  db.search(Cars.color == 'green')
  ```